# Create a Homepage for TeamSite with SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

What I am doing is to set the Home.aspx as the Homepage for my TeamSite. I've added a Web Part as Script Editor and put the jQuery script as below to remove or hide the left menu and the Home. However, whenever I click on the Logo, the link has been changed to a path `/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/`, the menu still appears. Please give me some advice to address my problem.

1. Did I work in the right way?
2. Is it impossible to make a Home.aspx as a Home page?
3. How can I change the link in the Logo when I click on that?

---

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sideNavBox").remove();
    $("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain .s4-die").remove();
    $("#pageTitle").remove();
});
</script>
```

---

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the Minimal Download Strategy feature activated, that's what "ruining" your URL, and it's also why the page Title and the menu is still showing.

Head to Site Settings > Site Features and deactivate Minimal Download Strategy.

And you could hide the elements using CSS instead.

```
<style type="text/css">
#sideNavBox {
display: none;
}
#contentBox {
margin-left: 220px;
}
#s4-titlerow{ 
display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

[Minimal Download Strategy overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for you code. That works pretty well to me.

Comment: Great! If you would like to make use of the whole page, just set #ContentBox to 20px instead of 220. This will give you a little more space to work with. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the Minimal Download Strategy feature for the script to work right.